# OpenXML altchunk ignore page setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

so I have this requirement I want to convert HTML to word and Insert it to my Content Control in word, I'm able to do that using altchunk component but the problem is it ignoring the page setup that I already defined in the word template so I use Multiple pages and 2 pages per sheet in my Page setup. So when I inserting the altchunk it always overlaps the divider line on my page.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentManagementService.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]GenerateHTMLModel html)
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk;
            AltChunk altChunk;
            List<string> listComponent = new List<string>()
            {
                 "ScopeofWorks", "ImplementationSchedule", 
                "Penalty", "Termination"
            };
            String base64File = "";
            byte[] templateFile = File.ReadAllBytes("X:/Test/Test/Document2.docx");
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            using (MemoryStream templateStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                templateStream.Write(templateFile, 0, (int)templateFile.Length);

                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateStream, true))
                {
                    PropertyInfo[] props = html.GetType().GetProperties();
                    mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                    Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    foreach (var property in props)
                    {
                        if (listComponent.Contains(property.Name))
                        {
                            string  htmlChunk = property.GetValue(html, null).ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlChunk))
                            {
                                string altChunkID = property.Name;
                                doc.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

                                chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Xhtml, altChunkID);

                                using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                                {
                                    using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))
                                    {
                                        stringStream.Write(htmlChunk);
                                    }
                                }

                                altChunk = new AltChunk();
                                altChunk.Id = altChunkID;
                                SdtElement element = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>()?.Val == property.Name);
                                element.InsertAfterSelf<AltChunk>(altChunk);
                                element.Remove();
                            }


                        }
                    }

                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                    doc.SaveAs("X:/Test/Test/Test.docx");

                }

                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(templateStream.ToArray());

                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                 new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "test.docx"
                    };

                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            }
            return result;


    }


  public class GenerateHTMLModel
    {

        public string ScopeOfWorks { get; set; }//ScopeOfWorks
        public string ImplementationSchedule { get; set; } //ImplemantionSchedule
        public string Penalty { get; set; }//Penalty
        public string Termination { get; set; }//Termination

    }
```

[image: Word]
That's the code that I use to convert HTML element to word and Replace my content control, Can we resize the altchunk or what is the workaround for this thanks

Edit : here is my document2 file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jZghrMUyd_plUNHOX0bHaDf3eiDphLBo

The HTML

```
<p>Test Executive Summary</p>\n\n<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width:500px\">\n\t<tbody>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>Ini Cuma atEST</td>\n\t\t\t<td>HANYA TEST</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>YA</td>\n\t\t\t<td>YA</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>YA</td>\n\t\t\t<td>YA</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t</tbody>\n</table>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n
```

Lorep Ipsum HTML from CKEditor

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate fringilla tellus, sit amet venenatis risus sollicitudin sed. Sed et arcu sed ligula pulvinar vestibulum. Donec id ex bibendum, tristique elit quis, ullamcorper felis. Integer ornare semper enim. Suspendisse in bibendum augue. Suspendisse ultricies justo eget odio maximus tincidunt. Phasellus sit amet dolor pretium, semper urna vel, sodales libero. Cras placerat ante non sapien euismod, non elementum mi hendrerit. Mauris egestas tristique ipsum at tincidunt. Nullam neque velit, aliquam nec scelerisque ac, mollis nec augue. Nullam quam sapien, egestas id imperdiet non, blandit vel lorem. Pellentesque porta augue sed risus iaculis, quis semper felis tristique.</p>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the Page Setup you're using. Could you provide the steps in the Word UI to set that up, please, so that we can be sure we're testing properly? The screen shot looks odd... if two pages / page were activated I'd expect the two pages to be the same size. This look more like two newspaper columns, to me. The next question would then be: WHY is the document set up like this?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the screenshot, can you instead upload your "Document2.docx" file? Anyway, I think the easiest approach would probably be to place the Content Control in a separate section (use "Section Break (Continuous)") which has the desired size and margins.

Comment: hi  @MarioZ and I update my question with my document file thanks

Comment: hi @CindyMeister oke let me check the document template again and make sure if it's multiple-page or two newspaper column

Comment: @CindyMeister hi this is multilanguage document that why the text is side by side

Comment: Then please give the steps to set up a test environment. People here, generally, will not d/l documents for security reasons. And the site rules are: all information for answering a question needs to be *in* the question.

Comment: okay, so I use asp net with 4.72 net frameworks in this example and use DocumentFormatOpenXML SDK for the word processing. I update the using package in the question

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang this is the result I get (the red text is imported HTML chunk): https://1drv.ms/w/s!AnZjjTv0yxQvjT4RUt5pMLff2Rbb?e=C6duZb  
I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, can you edit the document and show me what you want to have? Anyway, your SDK is limited to the size of cell in which it exists. If that is your problem then just move the SDK outside of a cell, or merge two cells so that the SDK will occupy the whole row.

Comment: Hi @MarioZ, how can you get the result clean like that, do you change the code or the template can you try the HTML table I give in above when I try to generate with my code I will get the result like above screenshot the table overlaps to the other side. do you mean to move my content control tag outside the cell? but what I want is my generated HTML is not exceed the size of the existing cell size.

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I see now, the problem is that HTML table, it has "width:500px" which ends up breaking your layout. Note, you could disable the "Automatically resize to fit contents" option on the tables in your template document ("Table Properties" -> "Options..." -> "Automatically resize to fit contents"), but in that case this HTML table will end up being cut.

Comment: @MarioZ oh so the HTML will be cut but the layout will still remain, right? Okay, maybe I need to make code to replace the width in my code too. Hi,  can you give me the HTML you have when I try to Convert my Lorep Ipsum HTML from Ckeditor  I get error word found unreadable content, but I don't see an error with my table from Ckeditor

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang yes, with that option disabled your layout should remain. Regarding the HTML, I'm using the one you provided.

Comment: @MarioZ hi I get corrupt word when try to convert HTML paragraph, Do you know why? And how you able to convert it without any error?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I think that HTML content must begin with either "DOCTYPE", "html" or "body".

Comment: @MarioZ oh I see let me try that first, Yes my HTML is only contained <p> tag for now

Comment: hi, @MarioZ is altchunk not supported in office online, because I can open it but I can't edit it.

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang also note MS Word is the only application I know that supports altChunk. In other words, it doesn't work in any other Word application like LibreOffice, OpenOffice, etc.